# template and overloading istream

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I don't know what is wrong when trying to overload >> and <<

```
template<class T, int N> class vector{
    friend istream &operator>> <T,N>(istream &, vector &);
    friend ostream &operator<< <T,N>(ostream &, const vector &);
};

template<class T, int N>
istream &operator>>(istream &input, vector<T,N>& v)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        input >> v.component[i];
    return input;
}
```

The g++ compiler says

```
vector.h:22:17: error: template-id ‘operator>><double, 2>’ for 
‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, vector<double, 2>&)’ 
does not match any template declaration
friend istream &operator>> <T,N>(istream &, vector &);
             ^
vector.h:23:17: error: template-id ‘operator<< <double, 2>’ for
‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const vector<double, 2>&)’
does not match any template declaration
friend ostream &operator<< <T,N>(ostream &, const vector &);
             ^
```

Comment: is `vecotr` you own class, or is it `std::vector` ??

Comment: It's my own class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a declaration of the template before the point it is made friend (i.e. the friend clause can't declare the template like it does for functions).

```
template<class T, int N> class vector;
template<class T, int N>
istream &operator>>(istream &input, vector<T,N>& v);
template<class T, int N>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &input, vector<T,N> const& v);

template<class T, int N> class vector{
    friend istream &operator>> <T,N>(istream &, vector &);
    friend ostream &operator<< <T,N>(ostream &, const vector &);
};

template<class T, int N>
istream &operator>>(istream &input, vector<T,N>& v)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        input >> v.component[i];
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written the overload is indicative of a function template specialization. Hence the error since there was no previously-declared primary template. If this is the primary definition (which it *is*) you only need the template arguments from the enclosing class declaration because they are impiled when you use the class name as an argument:

```
template<class T, int N> class vector {
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &, vector &);
    friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &, const vector &);
};
```

That is only special for the in-class declaration of the function. You could also accept template arguments of different types and values:

```
template<class T, int N> class vector {
    template<class T2, int N2>
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &, vector<T2, N2> &);

    template<class T2, int N2>
    friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &, const vector<T2, N2> &);
};
```